# Split parameters in Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on getting device status based on mac selection. I am passing form selection values through ajax with parameters as:

```
{"parameter"=>",Device.test\n", "mac"=>["5C:E3:23:88:33", "10:56:68:5A:A1"], "protocol"=>{"test"=>"true", "pil"=>"false"}, "id"=>""}
```

I have two mac values in the ajax call. I am getting ajax parameters as below:

```
@macAddress = params[:mac].first
```

I get only one mac value (`5C:E3:23:88:33`) in the controller.

How do I get two parameters in controller and perform execution twice?

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the both of the values you can simply acces like below

```
@mac_address_first,@mac_address_second = params["mac"][0], params["mac"][1]
```

or

```
params[:mac].each do |value|
  puts value
end
```

So you can used values for different purpose.

Comment: Thanks.But Mac value will be dynamic.Sometime 1 vale sometime 5 mac, user can select.

Comment: Base on the values you can also used the each loop inside it

Comment: if @macAddress.include? (",")
          paramArrayMac = @macAddress.split(/\s*,\s*/)
          total_params_mac = paramArrayMac_to_s.length
        end

Comment: If i am getting nill value as length

Comment: params["mac"].length it is simple or you can used .count also

Comment: If the solution work for you please accept my solution as answer @Raja1983

Comment: thanks.I am getting length.I am trying below                                             deviceCount = params[:mac].length
        @macAddress = params[:mac][deviceCount]

Comment: params[:mac].first is required ?

Comment: No i did not see the [deviceCount] in your params you can simply get your count by  @devise_count = params["mac"].length if you want to store the several address please use each lopp and do whatever you want

Comment: Thanks.I am trying following params[:mac].each do |mac|.It will also getting status of one device.will it take multiple values?